# What is one word for "more or less equal"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

The want to convey the meaning of a phrase "more or less equal". The quality being compared is skill. For example: we are more or less equally skilled to code.

Comment: This is a matter of [General Reference](http://thesaurus.com/browse/more+or+less?s=t).

Answer (score 3):

Our coding skills are [comparable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comparable).

> 2: similar, like

Answer (score 2):

**More or less** is the same as *approximately* or *roughly*.

Comment: Or simply “about”.

Comment: But what about the OP's request for a word for "approximately equal"?